# Adding scripts to head magento 2

Tags: magento2, javascript

So I found that you are able to add any script to the head tag of your `Magento 2` site via the `Magento 2` interface `content->configuration->html head-> scripts and sheets`.

I've added a:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="site/js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Is this Ok ? Any downsides etc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One major downside i see it will be applied to all pages  i.e. script will be included on all pages even if you require or not .
You can use your  tag in your layout and add Js only to pages that you require

Also it will be skipped from any bundling or merging of JS that magento does for performance optimisation.